# Is it possible to use ECMAScript modules (ESM) in SVG documents?

Tags: javascript, svg, browser, es6-modules

Or will it be supported in future versions of browsers? I've been thinking about this and tried to read up on the topic, but I couldn't figure it out. I also tried the following (which did not work in either Chrome 96 or Safari 14):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">

    <script type="module">
        import { demo } from './demo.js'

        const test = new demo();
        console.log('x', test);
    </script>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" />
</svg>
```

Is it possible? Will it be possible? Is there a workaround?

Comment: The [specification says no](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/interact.html#ScriptElement). The solution - get the specification changed then get browser vendors to implement it (or implement it for them given that they are all open source).

Comment: How about doing the script in the (native JavaScript) Web Component ``connectedCallback`` ?

Comment: Changing the spec is a bit further than I'd hoped to go with this, to be honest. Right now the SVG is embedded as `object` in a HTML document, so I can just run the ESM from there and access the SVG via `svgele.contentDocument`. It would be nicer though, if my script could be contained in the actual SVG file.
Is `connectedCallback` a good solution to accomplish this? How would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Very basic example

```js
customElements.define("svg-component", class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback(){
    this.innerHTML = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="${this.getAttribute('fill')}" />
</svg>`;
    // Your JS here
  }
});
```

```css
svg-component{
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<svg-component fill="red"></svg-component>
<svg-component fill="yellow"></svg-component>
<svg-component fill="blue"></svg-component>
```